# How to Pass Multiple Packages to packagesToScan property in Spring using XML Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-orm

Assume i have two packages **com.test1** and **com.test2** in different modules called **M**1 (com.test1) and **M2** (com.test2).

Now in the following example i configured **module1** package.

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test1" />
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendor" />
       <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
   </bean>
```

But i want to configure Module2 package as well in **packagesToScan** property. How to configure.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found answer my self.

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
     <property name="packagesToScan">
         <array>
              <value>com.test1</value>
              <value>com.test2</value>
         </array>
     </property>       
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendor" />
     <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>
```

Comment: The javadoc for packagesToScan says: `packagesToScan one or more base packages to search, analogous to Spring's component-scan configuration for regular Spring components`, which implies that comma/semicolon/space/tab/linefeed-separated packages should also work.

Comment: That appears to be correct, @Dormouse. I tested this with comma-separated packages and it works for me.

Comment: Awesome Example Reddy.